# How to model friction in physics engines

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, rigid-body-dynamics

How does one model and simulate friction in Rigid body systems?

For example a rigid box moving across a plain which has variable friction coefficients with respect to location. It's not clear to me how one incorporates distributed forces against the box which account for sections across two different areas.

Comment: How do you currently implement collision resolution?

Comment: Are you asking about the _details_ for friction modeling or the overall process? This question requires a lot more details to be effectively answered.

Comment: I'm interested in how you would model the above. Conceptually I understand how you implement constraints and evolve the object constraints using Eulers equation but friction is still not clear to me. My naive understanding of collision is an impulse is added to correct object intersection at the intersection point in the direction normal to the intersected polygon.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution to your question, but here's how I implement friction (impulse-based physics engine): the collision constraint is like $\dot C=(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf v_1)\cdot\mathbf n\cong\mathbf J_n\cdot\tilde{\mathbf v}$. In other words the constraint enforces the relative velocity projected onto the contact normal subspace to be 0. Friction is basically the same, but for the contact *tangent* subspace, so $\mathbf J_t$ is just $\mathbf J_n$ with $\mathbf n\to\mathbf t$ everywhere. Finally, the frictional impulse needs to be clamped: $|\mathbf I_f|\le\mu|\mathbf I_n|$.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Perhaps my question wasn't completely clear. Basically my issue is in relation to an object touching multiple parts of another object at the same time(perhaps infinity points) for example two blocks laying flat. Now if the blocks have the same material properties throughout you could basically make an approximation and say OK, they are parallel but you still have a problem with how you handle forces. Ex friction should resist rotational movement of a block and translational but it's not clear how this works since the boxes are interfacing across the whole face.

Comment: Even more difficult is if the material properties differ along a face so basically you have two different frictions applied to the bottom of the top box, one for each section it sits on.